# Almost at end of probationary... ask for overtime?

Tags: work-time, overtime, probation, salaried-pay

I started my current job around 5 months ago and my probationary is due to end in a few days. I have a review scheduled with my boss once it's complete.

Would this be a good time to put myself forward for extra work? I could do with the money. I'm thinking if I were to occasionally work a 6 day week that would boost my finances, and also help take some of the workload off some of my peers.

One of my colleagues has recently left, I'm currently unsure whether she'll be getting replaced.

It is only a small company so I feel it could benefit my boss if I were to work the occasional extra day, as it might reduce the need to be hiring extra staff.

I know that my company does pay for overtime, but I've not heard of anyone willing to regularly working an extra day by default.

Might I be best waiting longer? Or just not mention it at all?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Ask your boss. If it looks like they may need the extra help, I wouldn't see a problem with asking. The worst they can say is "no", but even if they say "no", they'll know who they can call first should an emergency come up and they need extra manpower.

Comment: Welcome new user. Thanks for the excellent question.

Comment: Do you plan to tell you are ready *sometimes* and overtime days are individually agreed with you, or do you plan to install that on a regular basis? Be clearly aware that the latter could quickly and silently establish as an expectation in you that could be hard to escape. Don't step into burnout!

Comment: You use the salaried-pay tag? you do know that you don't  normally get overtime outside of a minority of salaried  jobs that have elements of a shift system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I were to occasionally work a 6 day week

There is no need to get creative with this. It's perfectly normal to enquire about what overtime you can expect to get, and make it clear that you are open to doing extra hours.